# Bluefoot Pagebuilder in Magento 2.3.x CE?

Tags: magento2

I searched a bit but did not find an official statement for that. So, is the Bluefoot Pagebuilder included in Magento 2.3.x Community Edition or will it definitely be included in future releases of the CE?

Thanks!

Comment: This is only available for EE versions [Check here](https://www.bluefootcms.com/bluefoot-pagebuilder-for-magento-2.html)

Comment: Right @kishan
Magento does not release page builder for the Magento 2.3 Open source / community version.

Comment: @kishan-savaliya ,Please post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Bluefoot Pagebuilder is only available for **Enterprise Edition**. Check more info [here](https://www.bluefootcms.com/bluefoot-pagebuilder-for-magento-2.html).

The OpenSource version does not have this feature.

**Update**

Page Builder now available in latest **Magento 2.4.3** version.

Comment: CE needs this feature. Otherwise clients will continue to ask for things like wordpress being installed and integrated with magento